# Date output in 12hr format

Tags: linux, date

I am using the date command in my script to get both date & time by adding some minutes.

```
date --date 'now + 60 minutes'
Mon Oct 31 09:45:46 IST 2022
```

Currently I am getting the output in 24Hr format. How can I get it in 12Hr format?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to solve that.

**Solution 1:**

According to `man date`:

> %r     locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., 11:11:04 PM)

So you should use something like `+%r` but If you only use this then you will get the output in the following format:

```bash
09:54:32 PM # HH:MM:SS (AM|PM) format.
```

So if you want to get the same output format: `Mon Oct 31 09:45:46 IST 2022` you should use this (I'm not sure if exists a shorter way to print with that format):

```bash
date --date 'now + 60 minutes' '+%a %b %d %r %Z %Y'
```

**Solution 2:**

You can set the `LC_TIME` variable to `en_US.UTF-8` (actually that's my current setting on LC_TIME and when I use `date` I get the output in 12Hr format). You could run:

```bash
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" date
```

or

```bash
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
date
```

Comment: `%I` is the 12 hour time format character

Comment: @roaima nice! Thanks for the suggestion.